# Getting N + 1 query while working with Active Storage attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my code that is giving me N + 1 query.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :resumes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many_attached :cover_letters, dependent: :destroy
end

class ResumesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.includes(resumes_attachments: :blob).find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.includes(resumes_attachments: :blob).find(params[:user_id])

    if @user.resumes.attach(params[:user][:resume])
      redirect_to new_user_resume_path(@user)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

I have commented out everything in a view to make sure nothing is happening there. Bullet gem is only complaining when create action fails and `render :new` is triggered. For success create action bullet gem is not giving any error.

But when I check server log `ActiveStorage::Blob` is being called so many times. What am I missing ?. I am using Rails 6.

**UPDATE:**

Below is my log.

```
    ↳ app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "13e9e539-8c45-473f-b849-9e459646a1a1"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "2581e71d-98e3-4edc-afb8-310e699dde00"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "59ad2a58-dafe-4983-83d0-ce27ba37ff01"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "6f3431c2-8bb7-4348-a9d9-d36a4e8ea6bb"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "ac925113-8f42-4d12-aa04-842a812e57ab"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "bd753376-408b-497b-b4f9-8cdd4c85c23e"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "d48b3658-bb81-472b-b9b9-8da341a55ab6"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "e098a866-e14d-4477-8f4d-bd48389d0831"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/resumes_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

**UPDATE 2**

I also tried `User.with_attached_resumes.find(id)` but still same problem

**UPDATE 3**

Below is my code from `new.html.erb` page

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: user_resumes_path(@user), method: :post, local: true do |f| %>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
            <div class='statistic-item'>
              <%= f.file_field :resume, class: 'form-control file-field' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row mrg-top-30'>
          <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
            <div class='form-group text-center'>
              <%= f.submit 'Upload Resume', class: 'btn btn-primary theme-bg' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

### **Solution**

I managed to solve the issue but I don't know why it works. Basically I have to include `cover_letters` as well and then N + 1 query is solved. This is very strange that I have to include `cover_letters` when I am trying to attach just resume. Below is my working code for `create` action

```
@user = User.includes(resumes_attachments: :blob, cover_letters_attachments: :blob).find(params[:user_id])
```

OR

```
@user = User.with_attached_resumes.with_attached_cover_letters.find(params[:user_id])
```

If anyone have explanation for this behavior then please let me know. Thanks

Comment: How is ActiveStorage::Blob called in the log? Could it be just that an attachment is being uploaded and some preview images (blobs) are created?

Comment: @JussiHirvi I have updated the log file. But no I am not creating any preview images.

Comment: @mechnicov I commented out `new.html.erb` except button to upload resume and I am still getting same problem.

Comment: @mechnicov I have uploaded code for my view.

Comment: There is a classic meme that says that developers don't know why their code breaks and neither they know why their code works. If that last part of your question is a SOLUTION, then you should post it as an answer. Maybe later we can discuss about the reason why it happens.